# YouTrack commands stripped from GIT commit messages

Tags: git, integration, teamcity, commit, youtrack

I've got a YouTrack and TeamCity server, properly configured for integration with each other.  I commit my work to GitHub, which TeamCity monitors.  The goal is to allow me to commit changes and include in those commits YouTrack commands that update the issues I work on.

The problem I am facing is that when I make a git commit such as the one below:

```
Fix appearance of content tip edit icon.

[FIXED]     Tip on storage type passwords had a missing edit icon.

#MP-5 fixed
```

GIT strips the last line, because it looks like commentary, and the commit message contains only this:

```
Fix appearance of content tip edit icon.

[FIXED]     Tip on storage type passwords had a missing edit icon.
```

Meaning, no YouTrack command, and no issue update.

I proceeded to try alternatives, such as:

```
Fix appearance of content tip edit icon.

[FIXED]     Tip on storage type passwords had a missing edit icon.

MP-5 fixed
```

and

```
Fix appearance of content tip edit icon.

[FIXED]     Tip on storage type passwords had a missing edit icon.

- #MP-5 fixed
```

But those didn't trigger YouTrack commands (even though YouTrack did see the commit message).

So the question is basically:

How do I solve this workflow problem?  Note that I do not want to disable commentary stripping in GIT, because that will break git commit -av (which contains a nicely formatted diff overview of my changes in comments).  Am I going to have to resort to invoking the YouTrack REST API using some custom code that parses my commit messages?  Has this been done before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
Fix appearance of content tip edit icon.

[FIXED]     Tip on storage type passwords had a missing edit icon.

^MP-5 fixed
```

It should work according to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-10051